# Check if all array value exist in another array value

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array that i want to match with another array, all the value inside the first array must be inside the second array, so if second array length is less than the first array length it automatically become false. for example:

```
$products = array("soap","milk","book");
$availableProducts = array("soap","tea","oil","milk","book");
$this->matchArray($products,$availableProducts); //return true because  all $products value inside $availableProducts value too

$products = array("soap","milk","book");
$availableProducts = array("milk","tea","book","soap","oil");
$this->matchArray($products,$availableProducts); //return true because  all $products value inside $availableProducts value too

$products = array("soap","milk","book");
$availableProducts = array("soap","tea","oil","salt","paper");
$this->matchArray($products,$availableProducts); //return false because  only one of $products value inside $availableProducts value

$products = array("soap","milk","book");
$availableProducts = array("milk","book");
$this->matchArray($products,$availableProducts); //return false because  only two of $products value inside $availableProducts value
```

Comment: Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_diff()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

> array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays
>
> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
<?php

$products = array("soap","milk","book");
$availableProducts = array("soap","tea","oil","milk","book");

$difference = array_diff($products,$availableProducts);

if(count($difference)==0){

  echo "all products availabale";
}else{

  echo implode(',',$difference) ." are not available";
}
```

Output:-

1. https://eval.in/989587
2. https://eval.in/989588
3. https://eval.in/989593
4. https://eval.in/989596

Comment: so if the second array length i want to compare is less than the first array, the $difference will also be > 0 ?

Comment: @mileven  yes you are right

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides a wide range of [array functions](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

You are looking for [array_diff()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), which according to docs:

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.